# Is it possible to create OptionButton Switch Effect?

Tags: excel, vba

Something like this:

```
Private Sub opt01_Click()
If opt01.Value = True Then
opt01.Value = False
Else
opt01.Value = True
End If
```

It would be suitable for my formDesign, instead of looking for and importing some similar small picture.

Comment: Why not use a checkbox instead?

Comment: Because it's not rounded. I tried, but - it doesn't suit.

Comment: So you want a checkbox that looks like a optionbutton?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't exists. I hope, somehow is possible to change the functionality of an OptionButton.

Comment: Can you post a sample image of how your form looks?  I can't see any good reason to use an option button as a checkbox, but I'm curious to see why you're opting to do it this way.

Comment: @joseph4tw, I will try Daniel's solution. ThankYou, AnyWay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an OptionButton's value is always true when the Click event runs, you will need to store its desired value in a variable. Here is an example using a Form Control Option Button within a sheet named Option Button 1 on sheet 1. This method is stored in a module.

```
Private optionClicked As Boolean
Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Dim o As OptionButton
    Set o = Sheets(1).Shapes("Option Button 1").OLEFormat.Object
    o.Value = Not optionClicked
    optionClicked = Not optionClicked
End Sub
```

Note however, that using this method, that clicking on any option button will make all other option buttons false. So to use multiple option buttons as check boxes, you will need to store the correct value of the option buttons (probably in an array)... and correct the values every time any option button is clicked.

Are you sure you can't use check boxes?

Comment: Daniel, you are anExcellentSolver. Thanks a Lot.